# LWJGL Display opens on the bottom of my screen

Tags: java, lwjgl

I am creating a game with LWJGL with java 7 64bits and I have a problem,

when I put in my code :

```
Display.setResizable(true);
```

The Display pop on the bottom of my screen like this :

[image]

If you can help me to fix this display answer this post :)

This is the code of my main class :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fi3fjszc4ozcipi/code.txt?dl=0

Comment: Are you moving the window somewhere in your code? Btw maybe you should consider actually posting at least some of your code relevant to this resizing that you want to be doing. Otherwise this might turn into a bunch of wild guesses what is and what can...

Comment: This is my code https://www.dropbox.com/s/fi3fjszc4ozcipi/code.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding

```
Display.setLocation(x,y);
```

Comment: It should be  comment.

Comment: Works only for the X position, i don't know why but Y position wont work correctly